# Django - logic behind displaying relational tables in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have multiple related tables defined in my Django models:

```
# first models.py

from django.db import models

class Character(models.Model):
    first_field = models.DateTimeField()
    second_field = models.TextField()

# second models.py

from django.db import models

class Op(models.Model):
    fk_character = models.ForeignKey('Character')
    some_field = models.DateTimeField()
    other_field = models.TextField()


class Participant(models.Model):
    fk_op = models.ForeignKey('Op')
    fk_character = models.ForeignKey('Character')
    some_other_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

For now, I'm sending this data from a view to template in a way like this:

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

from second.models import MainModel

def home(request):
    data = Op.objects.filter(some_field__isnull=True).order_by('-date')
    rc = RequestContext(request, {'data':data})
    return render_to_response('index.html', rc)
```

In this way I do have all the `Op` related data I need in my `index.html` template, but I'm struggling with logic to display this data in my template in a specific way. For example:

- display a list of all `Ops`,
- for each list item, check if `Character` is also a `Participant` in current `Op` item,
- if it isn't, display some button, if it is than don't display the button

I know that template shouldn't handle any programming logic, but I'm also not sure what would be the best approach to solve this. Should I do all the logic in my view and construct a new object and send that object to my view or is there an easy way to solve this in template with current object I'm sending?

Comment: from what you posted, I don't see any connection whatsoever between Character and Participant models and what does it mean that "Character is also a Participant"

Comment: "Character is also a participant" is not very clear , these seem to be completely disparate objects

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I omitted a field in `Participant` model. Updated my original post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your model:

```
class Op(models.Model):
    fk_character = models.ForeignKey('Character')
    some_field = models.DateTimeField()
    other_field = models.TextField()

    def check_if_participant(self):
        return bool(self.participant_set.all())
```

Display list of all `Ops`:

```
{% for op in data %}
   {{op.some_field}}

   {% if op.check_if_participant %}Yes - Character is participant {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about defining functions within the model -.- This is very close, but a bit wrong probably because I had a small error in my question. I'll try to adopt this to my needs in a bit...

Comment: Hm, actually I realized that I will probably need to write a templatetag for this, right?

Comment: if your question is what you really intend to do, then my answer would be sufficient

Comment: Agreed. That's why I upvoted :) Can you please tell me is it possible to do what I actually need after I edited my original post?

Comment: i dont see a need for a templatetag . Wont `{% if op.check_if_participant %}Yes - Character is participant{% else %} <button /> {% endif %}` work ?

Comment: Well, when I update my model and check that in my template, the condition always returns `True` if an `Op` has any participant in it, not only if logged in character is a participant of specific op.